# Find available device name in local subnet and rename device

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell

This is a fairly complicated and obnoxious situation I'm trying to resolve, so I'll try to simplify as much as possible.

**SITUATION:** My organization uses a site-based naming convention for windows PCs at remote sites.  These sites are not on a domain.  The naming convention is as follows:

> (Site ID)-(Device Purpose)(Device Number)-(Device Model)

Site ID is restricted to 5 characters.
Device Purpose is restricted to 2 characters.
Device Model is restricted to 4 characters.

Thus, a sample device name might look like this:

> ABCDE-FG12-9876

**ISSUE:**  Due to bad planning, a number of devices have incorrectly had the (Device Number) element of the name duplicated.  So, using the example above I might have two devices at site ABCDE both named `ABCDE-FG12-9876`.  I need to fix this without having to touch each device manually.

**PLAN:**  I am working on a PowerShell script that I want to do the following:

1. Identify the site's /24 subnet based on the current machine's IP address.
2. Use that subnet to ping all active windows machines on that subnet and put their machine names into an array.
3. Based on the data in that array, identify the first available (Device Number) not in use, rename the device and reboot it.

**PROBLEM:**  I have gotten to the point of building the array and trying to check its contents, and for reasons I cannot figure out, it's *only adding the name of the machine the script runs on* to the array, and not properly adding the rest of the machines in the site subnet.  I have read the code until my eyes cross, and tried re-using samples from StackOverflow and other sites and I feel like I am just spinning my tires and getting nowhere.

I am certainly open to any sort of alternative ideas as to how to accomplish my goal, but for reference, my code so far is below For right now, am just trying to output the contents of `$sitemachines` to the screen to validate that the correct information is being captured.

```
Function Iterate-Subnet($Subnet) {  #in the format of "10.10.10."
    $arrIPs = @();$arrValid = @() #Creates 2 arrays, one to hold the IP
                                  #addresses and the other to hold confirmed
                                  #Windows machines
    For($x=1; $x -lt 254; $x++) {
        #Starting at 1 and incrementing to 254, each time building a new IP
        #address based on the subnet
        $IPAddress = $Subnet + $x;$arrIPs += $IPAddress
    }
    ForEach ($IPfound in $arrIPs) {
        $ping = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='$IPfound'" #Ping each IP address in the subnet
        If ($ping.StatusCode -eq "0") {
             #Attempt to connect to each online machine using WMI, this
             #confirms whether it's a Windows machine
             $checkOS = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "$IPfound" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
             #Add this computer name to the valid array
             If ($checkOS -ne $null) {$arrValid += @($checkOS.CSName)}
        }
    }
    #Remove any duplicate entries, this accounts for any multihomed machines
    $arrValid = $arrValid | Select-Object -Unique
    #Return the valid array to any script you choose to call this function from
    return $arrValid 
}

#Split the computer name at the device position number
#and store the beginning and end into two variables
$computer = hostname
$cname1 = $computer.substring(0,8)
$cname2 = $computer.substring($computer.length -5,5)

#Find and define the site subnet for pingsweep
#referencing current machine IP Address
$getip = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 
$ip = $getip.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
$IPByte = $ip.Split(".")
$sitesub = ($IPByte[0]+"."+$IPByte[1]+"."+$IPByte[2]+".")

#build and retrieve the list of site machines
#from the function Iterate-Subnet
$sitemachines = Iterate-Subnet -Subnet "$sitesub"
Start-Sleep -s 30
$sitemachines.length
$sitemachines
```

Comment: Still looking at your code. While not an issue I can see several places where the code could be made more terse. What happens when you remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` from the `$checkOS` line? If you WMI is failing then your array wont be populated and you would not get errors. In your plan you have a sites subnet... you can have more than one subnet in a site ( thats just a nitpick).

Comment: Trying that now to see what it comes up with.  And no - in our environment each site is on a unique subnet and/or VLAN.  Otherwise, I don't think there would be any chance to make this work.

Comment: Tried that edit, and got a huge amount of red-text indicating access denied errors when trying to make the WMI connections.  I'm working in a shared lab, so that is expected - other devices in the lab are installed with other configurations and would not share the same username/password credentials.  However, I do not see a success for the ~10 lab machines that do share the correct credentials - just the failures.

Comment: are you able to run that command against a known machine? Does the wall of red make sense? You should get some errors for other devices like printers, switches and such but I feel you need to be sure WMI is not your issue.

Comment: Indeed - printers, IP phones, etc. inside the targetted subnets were why I had suppressed the errors in the first place.  However trying that line as a standalone, I am getting a very unexpected error when I try it against a single lab machine - it is kicking back an RPC service is unavailable error with an error code of 0x800706BA.   I'll investigate that further now. --  Thanks for the idea, I hope this bears fruit!

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to do my renaming,

```
$a = Import-Csv c:\ServerNames.csv -Header OldName, NewName
Foreach ( $Server in $a ) {Rename-Computer -ComputerName $Server.OldName -NewName $Server.NewName -DomainCredential Domain\username -Force -Restart}
```

Now this has its downfalls because you have to give it a CSV but you put the old name/ IP address in column 1 and put the new one in the second and run it. there is more work up front but less logic in the script to fail.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thought, but that would not really remove any of the manual work involved.  Building the CSV would just require manually inputting all the data -and avoiding that is the point of doing this via script.  At that point, I haven't saved significant time or effort from just manually renaming the devices.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your subnets seem to be /24 IPv4 subnets you could simplify your code by having the function take the host IP address (string) and return the new (integer) device number:

```
$pattern = '^(.{5}-.{2})(\d+)(-.{4})$'

function Scan-Subnet($ip) {
  $bytes = ([ipaddress]$ip).GetAddressBytes()

  1..254 | % {
    $bytes[3] = $_
    $addr = [ipaddress]$bytes

    if (Test-Connection $addr -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
      Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $addr |
        select @{n='DeviceNumber';e={[int]($_.CSName -replace $pattern,'$2')}} |
        select -Expand DeviceNumber
    }
  } | sort | select -last 1 | % { $_ + 1 }
}
```

`$pattern` is defined as a global variable with 3 groups, so it can be used for both extracting the device number and building the new name (see below).

The host IP address can be determined via WMI, so you could call the function like this:

```
$myIP = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled=True' |
        select -Expand IPAddress |
        select -First 1

$deviceNumber = Scan-Subnet $myIP
```

and rename the computer like this:

```
if ($deviceNumber -ne $null) {
  $newname = $env:COMPUTERNAME -replace $pattern, "`$1$deviceNumber`$3"
  Rename-Computer -NewName $newname -Restart
}
```

Since `Rename-Computer` isn't available prior to PowerShell v3 you could also use `netdom`:

```
& netdom $env:COMPUTERNAME /NewName:$newname /Reboot
```

Comment: That logic looks really promising.  I'll build a new version of the script with this and try it out first thing tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: Coming back to let you know - turns out that this didn't work for my needs.  Also, apparently our field devices were running an older version of Powershell, and some of the cmdlets I used in the larger script were not available.   I have gone with a very simplified version that just replaces the Device Number with a randomly generated number in a previously unused range.  It could potentially end up with a super small number of reduplicated names, but that will be few enough I can fix that manually.  Thanks for the assist, sorry it didn't work.

Comment: @DarrianSheffield FTR, the code I posted should work just fine with PowerShell v2 and above, except for `Rename-Computer`, which could be replaced by calling `netdom`. If you're still on PowerShell v1 you should seriously consider upgrading.